# Why there is loss of value when converting from int to float in the below code?

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
int value1 = 123456789;
float value2 = value1;
System.out.println(value1);
System.out.println(value2);
```

Output:

123456789 
123456792

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `float` type uses the same number of bits as `int` (32 bits) to represent floating point numbers in the larger range than `int` uses to represent only integers.

This causes a loss of precision, since not every `int` number can be represented accurately by a `float`. Only 24 bits are used to represent the fraction part of the number (including the sign bit), while the other 8 are used to represent the exponent.

If you assign this `int` value to a `double`, there won't be any loss of precision, since `double` has 64 bits, and more than 32 of them are used to represent the fraction.

Here's a more detailed explanation:

The binary representation of 123456789 as an int is :

```
00000111 01011011 11001101 0001 0101
```

A single precision floating point number is constructed from its 32 bits using [the following formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) :

```
(-1)^sign * 1.b22 b21 ... b0 * 2^(e-127)
```

Where `sign` is the left most bit (b31). b22 to b0 are the fraction bits, and bits b30 to b23 make the exponent e.

Therefore, when you convert the `int` 123456789 to `float`, you can only use the following 25 bits :

```
00000111 01011011 11001101 00010101
-    --- -------- -------- -----
```

We can safely get rid of any leading zeroes (except of the sign bit) and any trailing zeroes. This leaves you with the 3 least significant bits, which we must drop. We can either subtract 5 to get 123456784:

```
00000111 01011011 11001101 00010000
-    --- -------- -------- -----
```

or add 3 to get 123456792:

```
00000111 01011011 11001101 00011000
-    --- -------- -------- -----
```

Obviously adding 3 gives a better approximation.

Comment: Please explain me more detailed, does it have something to do with mantissa and exponent

Comment: @pramodkumar The fraction is also called the mantissa, so yes.

Comment: How do i overcome such loss of precision,when dealing with comparitively large numbers?

Comment: That's also explains, why float can hold values up to about `3*10^38`, but int only `2*10^9`.

Comment: @pramodkumar use `BigInteger` for big integers.