# confusing part of data type conversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, floating-point, integer

i read C# book, and there is this example. the question is, why the heck float lose the numeric "1" from int value???
isn't float have bigger magnitude?

```
int i1 = 100000001;
float f = i1; // Magnitude preserved, precision lost (WHY? @_@)
int i2 = (int)f; // 100000000
```

Comment: This link is in java but the explination about how float and int are are stored as bits is explained, very well. I will hunt for a C# version.

Possible duplicate of [Why there is loss of value when converting from int to float in the below code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903174/why-there-is-loss-of-value-when-converting-from-int-to-float-in-the-below-code)

Answer (score 1):

A float is a 32 bit number made up of a 24 bit mantissa and an 8 bit exponent.  What happens when

```
float f = ii;
```

is an attempt to squeeze a 32 bit integer into a 24 bit mantissa.  The mantissa will only store 24 bits (around 6-7 significant figures) so anything past the 6th or 7th digit will be lost.

If the assignment is made with a double, which has more significant digits, the value will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

`float` was not designed for big integer numbers. If you want to use big numbers and you know it is not always integers, use `double`.

```
   int i1 = 100000001;
   double f = Convert.ToDouble(i1);
   int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(f); // 100000001
```

If all integers and you will want to be able to do calculations with them use `Int64` instead of `int`.