# Java - infinite while loop with float

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am currently learnig java float-point numbers. I know, that a float have a specific amount of significant digets. I also know, that a float is represented in java like -1 or 1 * num * 10^x. Where num is the numer and 10^x is the decimal "point". But here we do not have a fraction of a number. How is a infinite loop here possible?

The code with infinite loop:

```
float f = 123456789;
while (f-- > 0) {
System.out.println(f);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the loop is infinite? What happens after f becomes 0?

Comment: f stays the same and no decrement. It is an infinite loop. It was a exam question at the university last year (example exam).

Comment: f is not precise enough to represent this number (f--) is the solution but why?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903174/why-there-is-loss-of-value-when-converting-from-int-to-float-in-the-below-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about floating point arithmetic. When you're decrementing the number you stumble upon the situation when you go through the number `f = 1.23456792E8` makes everything go wrong, because `f-1` and `f` have the same floating point representation here. So decrementing makes the number be itself, which leads to the infinite loop. Just check:

```
System.out.println(1.23456792E8f);
System.out.println(1.23456792E8f - 1);
```

What is so special about the number and why execution stops there? It's because the floating point representation of `123456789` is `1.23456792E8`. Already this gives us a gap of at least `3` due to the lack of precision of floating point numbers. Using `double` instead of `float` makes the program finish, but the issue will occur with higher numbers.

Comment: what do You mean by destroys everything?

Comment: the algorithm - thanks, I'll change it

Comment: why it isn't 0.23456792E8?

Comment: If you mean 1.23456789E8 - the number just has no floating point representation as far as I see, so it has to be the nearest to it. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: ahh thank you. But the f-- will decrement something but not in the relevant area?

Comment: `f--` is just short (at least this case) for `f=f−1`, but in this case it will still be `f` because of the lack of precission - it will perform the operation, but it will still be the same number.